# Bug mat-drawer-content height 100% angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

css:

```
.mat-drawer-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Hello, I have a problem that my content is not occupying a full screen, and a screen is creating a scroll, and there is no need, because of the header, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your full layout and style code - the bug is in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me**

```
.mat-drawer-container,
  .mat-drawer-content {
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `height: 100vh;` along with your other styles or try this alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue appearing on page load and since the side-nav was not opened, there was an empty div that appeared. So I made the changes below:

```
  .mat-drawer-container,
  .mat-drawer-content {
    height: auto;
  }
```